# Mac: Trying to run a python script but get an webdriver error

Tags: python

Trying to run a python script but getting error. Can anyone help me?
I installed a verison 3 but keeps telling me about version 2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "screen.py", line 10, in <module>
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
        os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> You can download ChromeDriver here:
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
>
> then add it either to your path, or put it in the same directory as
>   your python script or specify the location directly, e.g.
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')

Comment: looks like the script does not want to run, i get chrome opened and I get --ignore-certifcate-erros error